# 'One To Many' attribute value type should not be 'Book'

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a class Book annotated with @Entity and

```
@ManyToOne
    private BookStore bookStore;
```

I also have a class BookStore with this code

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookStore",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Book> books;
```

But I get an error in the BookStore class that states: 'One To Many' attribute value type should not be 'Book'. How do I fix this?

I tried adding mappedBy = "bookStore" and both of the classes are annotated with @Data and @Entity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `@JoinColumn` of `BookStore` entity in `Book` entity to specify the mapping of a foreign key column in a relationship between two entities like below.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bookstore_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
private BookStore bookStore;
```

With the help of @JoinColumnn annotation, Hibernate will generate the foreign key constraint in the database to establish the relationship between Book and BookStore entity.